# Is there a simple way to sort an array in Crystal?

Tags: arrays, crystal-lang

I'm new to Crystal and I find it fun to learn and work with.
What's a simple and quick way to sort an array?

Comment: The [documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/api/Array.html#sort-instance-method) usually helps ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what your Array actually contains i assume it's an Array(Int32) (array of integers).

You can easily sort an array of integers like

```
[4, 7, 2].sort { |x, y| y <=> x } # => [7, 4, 2]
```

Check the array spec in Crystal core for more info https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/bf6b743aa7649ed3ecc92dd06fde21f88460720a/spec/std/array_spec.cr#L998-L1047

Comment: That's a reverse sort, `[4, 7, 2].sort` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sort` like in `Ruby`

```
puts [7,3,2,8].sort #=> [2, 3, 7, 8]
```